# Using os.walk() to loop over files and open them

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, os.walk

I have my main directory which contains multiple folders and inside each folder there are files in the following order.

```
 7. ABCD.txt , 8. ABCD.txt, 9. ABCD.txt, 10. ABCD.txt , 11. ABCD.txt, 12.ABCD.txt etc.
```

I want to loop over all folders and identify only the .txt file. Once I have identified the .txt files, I want to read them in a specific order.

When I do this using my code, it reads it in the following order.

`10. ABCD.txt , 11. ABCD.txt, 12.ABCD.txt, 7. ABCD.txt , 8. ABCD.txt, 9. ABCD.txt`

Where I want to read it in natural human order that i have listed it.

This is what I have

```
path =os.getcwd()

for root,subdirs,files in os.walk(path):
    sorted(files,key=int)
    for file in files:
        if file.split('.')[-1]=='txt':
            lf=open(os.path.join(root,file), 'r')
            lines = lf.readlines()
            filt_lines = [lines[i].replace('\n', '') for i in range(len(lines)) if lines[i] != '\n']
            alloflines.append(filt_lines) 
            lf.close()
```

I have also used the following

````
def natural_key(string_):
    return [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in re.split(r'(\d+)', string_) if s]
```
To change the key that sorts my files in the order I want, but it keep returning an error.
````

Comment: Then sort your txt.file list after reading them 
 - whatever order you "see" might not be what the things are stored in. They are sorted lexicografically where '11' is smaller them '7' because '1' is smaller then '7'

Comment: [edit] your question - code does not belong into comments.

Comment: This `sorted(files,key=int)` is bound to crash your program if your file names do not consist of pure numbers.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I need to read the files in that specific order first because I have another function that pulls specific information based on the order I need.

Comment: `sorted(files,key=int)` also does nothing at all for your code - the result is not stored so it is a (costly) no-op that does nothing

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've 

granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. 

By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, 

please take a look at 
[**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code:

- find all text files first and store them in a list as tuple of *(path, number, filename)*
- sort the tuple list after finding all files
- process sorted files

like so:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()

# stores tuples of (path, number (or 999999 if no number), full filepath)
txt_files = []

for root,subdirs,files in os.walk(path):    
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            number, remains = file.split(".",1) # only split into 2, first parsed as number
            if number.isdigit():
                txt_files.append( (root, number, os.join(root,file)) )
            else:
                # txt files not starting with number ordered under 999999
                txt_files.append( (root, 999999, file) )

# tuple-sort: sorts by elements, if same - sorts by next element
# i.e. sorting by path then_by number then_by filename
for path,num,file in sorted(txt_files):
     print( path, num, file)
     # do something with the ordered files
```

Comment: I get the following error.
number, remains = file.split(".",2)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @Alan fixed - use file,split(".",1)

Comment: i think there was a missing path in txt_files.append( (root, number, os.path.join(root,file)) )

Comment: the code still gives the same output as my original code :(